# Error "Root element is missing" y "Unavaiable project" en Windows Forms C#

Tags: c#, windows-forms

El día de hoy me ocurrió un error, entré al visual studio, entre a mi aplicación y me mostró un error, no quería cargar el proyecto, me muestra una ventana la cual dice

> The project file could not be loaded. Root element is missing

y a continuación una dirección del archivo,

> C:\Users\M\source\repos\WindowsFormsApp2\WinfowsFormsApp2\ProjectReminders.csproj

Supongo que como dice, el archivo podría no estar en el lugar correcto, ya lo coloqué en la anterior dirección y sigue, también intenté borrar el proyecto de la solución e intentar de nuevo, pero sigue, nada.

**ACTUALIZACIÓN:**

Me di cuenta de que al ejecutarlo y salir error, se guardaron unos archivos y se duplicaban con cada error.
Esto Decían:

> Migration Report
>
> Overview
>
> Project Path Errors Warnings Messages
>
> ProjectR C:... 1    0        0
>
> ProjectR
>
> Message
>
> Projectr.csproj : Error on line 1.Expected "<" but found null character

Comment: El error parece claro. Tu archivo ProjectReminders.csproj que es un archivo xml tiene una estructura incorrecta. Tienes dos soluciones. O bien lo editas con un editor de texto y reparas lo que este mal, o bien directamente eliminas el proyecto, creas uno nuevo y  añades en el todos los formularios, referencias, etc... que tenía el antiguo.

Comment: Abrí el archivo en notepad++ y me dice que tiene el valor "null". Como podría pasar los formularios y eso?. Muchas gracias.

Comment: Simplemente crea otro proyecto, y ve añadiendo los formularios con "agregar/elemento existente"

Comment: Muchas gracias Pikoh.